# yield from two generators at the same time, and make the result a tuple

Tags: python, generator

I'm trying to know if there's a pythonic way to unroll two generators at the same time:

e.g. I have two files with the same number of lines. Of course, I could zip the lines after reading their entire content.

But is it possible to yield elements from the two generators at the same time ?
when I try to run such code, it complains:

```
return (yield from test, yield from predict)
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

here, `test` and `predict` are two generators obtained by opening two files this way :

```
with open(test_filename,"rt") as test:
    with open(predict_filename,"rt") as predict:
        for couple in yield_couples(test,predict):
            do_something(couple)

def yield_couples(test,predict,category):

    return (yield from test, yield from predict)
```

Comment: Why not `zip()` the file iterators together (or `itertools.zip_longest()` if they're not the same number of lines)?

Comment: Probably better to `izip` (or `itertools.izip_longest`), though.

Comment: I'm not clear on why you acknowledge `zip()` but then dismiss it as unsuitable. Its whole point is to do exactly what it seems like you want.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 because I had used it only on lists so far, and did not imagined it worked that indentically well on generators

Comment: @tmr232: You only need `itertools.izip` in Python 2 where the builtin `zip` is not a generator. Since the code is using `yield from`, it must be Python 3.3+, so that's not necessary.

Comment: Maybe open an interpreter and try it out next time? I keep one open at all times just to test things like this (it's generally faster than going to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), too).

Comment: @Tigerhawk if `print()` doesnt work the same on generatos and on lists, why would have i even thought that `zip()` would work all the same on both ? but I agree I should have dug more in the intuitive "zip" direction (repl or documentation)

Comment: `print()` kind of does work similarly on generators and `list`s: try `print(*my_iterable)` where `my_iterable` is either a generator or a `list`. The printed representation of each _bare_ object may be different, but their behaviors are comparable in many instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding, but it sounds like you're looking for zip(). You can do:

```
with open(test_filename,"rt") as test:
    with open(predict_filename,"rt") as predict:
        for couple in zip(test,predict):
            do_something(couple)
```